# How to rotate an animated div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, rotation

I have a jQuery animation where pictures slide from bottom to left. Now I want to rotate this div with `-ms-transform: rotate(90deg)`. After rotating this div, the animation is broken.

The animation should have a fixed infobox on the left side and pictures which slide from left to right on the right side. The Animation Container is rotated 90deg.

My animation:

```
$('#divImg0').animate({ "marginTop": -this.screenHeight, "Height": 0 }, "slow");
```

HTML:

```
<div style="-ms-transform: rotate(90deg); position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;">
    <div id="PictureContainer" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"> </div>
</div>

<div id="InfoBox" style="position: absolute; top: 0; height: 768px; width: 200px; padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: #000; z-index: 99;">
    <div style="-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);">wasd asd asd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should helpful.(expect internet explorer and opera)

http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html

Comment: I believe opera now supports rotation.